# MongoDB, Redis, MySQL- что выбрать?

Tags: mongodb, redis, база-данных, mysql

Имеется один социальный проект. 
Пользователи могут подписываться на категории сайта. Скажем на статьи. Если в БД добавляется (`Insert Mysq`l) статья, тогда отсылается `real time` сообщение о новой добавленной статье всем подписанными клиентам. 
Так же есть функция `Like`, как на `facebook`.

Соответственно, нужна быстрота всех этих процессов..
Кто, что может сказать, отталкиваясь от вопроса, какую БД и для чего лучше использовать и как должно быть правильно?

Comment: я бы выбирал среди mongoDB или MySQL. redis чуточку для другого, но делают и на нем.

Я бы брал то, что знаю лучше.

Comment: Меня больше смущает вопрос подбора БД применительно к ситуации.
В конкретно данном случае вопрос архитектуры приложения, которое будет обслуживать клиентов гораздо важнее чем БД.

Comment: Буду рад любым замечаниям и подсказкам и по архитектуре...

Comment: Необязательно выбирать что-то одно. Из Redis вы можете взять систему pub/sub, т.е делать уведомления, хранить там сессии. В Mongo же можно хранить статьи и профили пользователей.

Comment: Real time через HTTP? месье знает толк в извращениях.

Берите любую удобную базу, скорость работы с базой всё равно выше скорости сети.

Comment: Real time через HTTP? - да Node.js вам о чем-то говорит?

Answer (score 5):

Вы хотите использовать лишь одну базу данных в качестве хранилища? В современных проектах, для решения схожих задач могут использоваться все три базы одновременно. MySQL (а все чаще PosgreSQL) используется для хранения данных в нормализованном виде и выполнения транзакций. Если транзакции вам не нужны, от классической СУБД, завязанной на жесткий диск, можно смело отказаться.

MongoDB привлекательно как хранилище документов, так как у вас статьи, вы можете хранить их в денормализованном виде непосредственно в MongoDB, а за счет того, что она расположена в оперативной памяти - быстро отдавать их клиентам. Хорошая горизонтальная масштабируемость позволит вам быстро наращивать мощность вашего кластера при росте популярности проекта.

Redis привлекателен встроенным Pub/Sub-механизмом, однако, с ним нужно быть очень аккуратным, так как он однопоточный. В случае, если у вас запущен один инстанс Redis и на нем выполняются какие-то длительные операции - будет накапливаться очередь запросов (иногда значительная). Однако, он так же прекрасно масштабируется, класстеризуется и может выдерживать невероятное количество одновременных подключений.

PS. Если бы передо мной стояла ваша задача и я был ограничен лишь одной из трех баз данных, я бы ориентировался на MongoDВ: она позволяет хранить данные в виде готовых документов с одной стороны, с другой - позволяет строить на коллекции до 64 индексов, позволяя доводить скорость выборки до невероятных значений (которых вы скорее всего никогда не увидите на MySQL). Redis хотя и допускает хранение нескольких типов данных, все же удобен в качестве кэша, в нем не всегда удобно хранить сложно-структурированные данные (текст, ключевые слова, авторы и т.п.).